# Using VS2019 to create a WebService

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-services, visual-studio-2019

I want to use Visual Studio 2019 to create a WebService inside an existing .NET project, using C#. Searching the internet, all I could find were tutorials for older VS versions...

How can I create it, and what's the best approach for receiving POST data using Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: In exactly the same way as the previous version. You create a WCF service. The emphasis on `POST` is meaningless since SOAP works with POST anyway

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Considering you have your solution opened:

- Right click on the project name (at the solution explorer), go to *"Add"* and than *"Add new item..."*

[image: first step]

- Select *"Visual C#"*, scroll down, select *"Web Service (ASMX)"* and click *"Add"*.

[image: second step]

A file called *WebService.asmx* (Or the name you entered) was create on the root folder of your project. Inside, you should see that code:

```cs
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/WebService.cs" Class="WebService" %>
```

This file is just used to call the code, at *"~/App_Code/WebService.cs"*. So if you want to call it from **POST / GET**, you should use:

`www.host.com/pathTo/projectRoot/WebService.asmx/functionName?Params=values`

After opening *"~/App_Code/WebService.cs"*, you should see something like that:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public WebService()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

}
```

Now, you can customize your code to receive and process **POST / GET** data.

Note that instead of using `Request["param"]`, you should use `HttpContext.Current.Request["param"];`.

Comment: With the wrong answer too - ASMX services became obsolete when WCF came out and don't support any of the WS-* interoperability standards

Comment: Exatcly. I did that because I don't found anything about this, and took some time to find how.

Comment: @Brhaka on the contrary, there are entire chapters in the online docs on how to create SOAP services, hundreds of courses and tutorials. The answer for the last 11 years is WCF, not ASMX. They are thoroughly documented.

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard as long as the answer isn't wrong. This answer is wrong though - yes, there's a *lot* of documentation already and no, you don't created SOAP services with the ASMX template

Comment: ASMX is not the most recommended since is old, but I use to integrate thousands of registers, without problems.

Comment: @RyanWilson in this day and age the answer would be ASP.NET Core GRPC :P

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is really common to use old and obsolete APIs, softwares, etc because of price, compatibility and even preference.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as well as saying "They are thoroughly documented" it'd be more useful to actually link to the relevant documentation.  If I'm completely new to this (and someone searching the web with terms that will find this answer probably will be) how do I know what documentation there is and where?  For example, I've just tried searching the VS2019 help and it's less useful than this answer.  Clearly I am searching for "the wrong thing" - but what _should_ I be looking for?

Comment: @SomeoneElse `WCF tutorial` would do. The first link after the ads is a page from `learn.microsoft.com` which has *multiple* sites, tutorials and references. After that come thousands of links to other tutorials, courses, blog posts and articles. The wrong thing you search for is `VS2019`. The library/technology isn't tied to the tool. The problem is findint a *good* tutorial out of the 2M hits, not lack of hits

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks - that first link does seem to be the root of most of the useful documentation (for the benefit of everyone else it's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/getting-started-tutorial ).  Some of the links from there are a bit incomplete (there are too many variables for it to be otherwise, I guess), so it'd be good to be able to find out which ones work and which (because of e.g. unspoken assumptions etc.) don't

Comment: I wish this was current.

Comment: Now I read that WCF is dead and ASP.NET Core GRPC  is not supported on Azure or IIS. Argh!

Comment: in case "WebService.asmx" template or ASP.NET Web Application project template is missing, use visual studio installer and add "asp.net and web tools" component

Answer (score 6):

this is how I created a project with an asmx page.
[image: create new project]

[image: create an empty on]

[image: right click for a new item]

[image: and look for webservice.asmx]