# How to add a service reference in Xamarin forms cross platform?

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541371/how-to-add-a-service-reference-to-xamarin-pcl-on-visualstudio-2017)

Referring to this link it says to edit the .csproj file but in my created project there is no In the "TargetFrameworkProfile" enter "Profile78

Please help in how to add a service reference

Comment: I would guess your project is not a PCL but actually a .net standard 2 project.

Comment: @MouseOnMars, Yes the project is not PCL and it is  a .net standard 2 project.Please help me in how to add a service reference, i have already created a ASMX Web service which i wanted to add in Xamarin forms(Cross platfofm)

Answer (score 0):

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click project -> **Add**, and then click **Add Service Reference**.
2. In the Address box, enter the URL for the service, and then click Go
   to search for the service. If the service implements user name and
   password security, you may be prompted for a user name and password.
3. In the Services list, expand the node for the service that you want
   to use and select an entity set.
4. In the Namespace box, enter the namespace that you want to use for
   the reference. Click **OK** to add the reference to the project.

For more details you could check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-add-update-or-remove-a-wcf-data-service-reference?view=vs-2019#add-a-service-reference

Comment: Couldn't find Add Service Reference in project, that section is missing in my project file.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 has released .You could update your IDE firstly and try again . It will be available in 2019 .

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57328629/using-vs2019-to-create-a-webservice

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I wanted to add a service(Add service reference) to my Xamarin project app(cross platform) not the web application project. please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can I add a ASMX web service in vs2019 using Add service reference for Xamarin cross platform project. please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57328629/using-vs2019-to-create-a-webservice .

Comment: Sorry but I wanted to add a service reference for Xamarin project not web application project. Is it possible in 2019?.Help me please

Comment: You can have a try because I haven't tested it until now .

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Already I have installed VS 2017 (Professional and Community) but there is no such feature for Add Service Reference in Xamarin cross platform project.. Hence I'm unable to add a service for login using ASMX.

Comment: As I said , update the IDE to VS 2019 firstly . It will be available on it .

Comment: Hi, in VS 2019 there is no option for Add Service Reference. Please help me

Comment: Post your problem to  **Help->Send Feedback->Report a problem**  .